# breaking an if loop inside a for loop and printing output

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe and I would like to loop over it with an if condition.

```
head(d)
   col1 col2 col3
1   1   1  2.785561
2   2   1  5.765601
3   3   1  1.606134
4   4   1  3.475117
5   5   1  3.352561
6   6   1  2.849907
...
...
...
```

I would like to sum up each value in the dataframe and if the value gets larger than 10 I want to record the index of the loop and end the loop. I only want to record one number. What I have is:

```
for (j in 1:nrow(d)){                     
    if (d[j,3] > 10){
      break } 
    output = j }
```

but the output value ends up being larger than the real answer, which should be 3.

```
  output
[1] 17
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A more [r](/questions/tagged/r) way to do this would be to use `cumsum` and `which`:

```
which(cumsum(d$col3) > 10)[1]
# [1] 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `for` loop, you could use:

```
sum1 <- 0
for (j in 1:nrow(d)) {
sum1 <- sum1 + d$col3[j]
if (sum1 > 10) {
    break
  }
output = j + 1
} 

output
#[1] 3
```